# How do I append a list with links from a googlesearch to another list using loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, append, google-search

I started learning Python few weeks ago.

With this code I want to google search each str in CitiesList and put the top 3 URL google return inside another list using a loop. Simple like that but not that simple for me to code lol

This code returns only the city1 results but what I want to do is the Links[] to have 18 URLs inside of it. -> 6 cities x 3 URLs/city = 18 URLS

Thanks! :)

```
import pandas as pd
from googlesearch import search

Cities = [city1, city2, city3, city4, city5, city6]
y = []
x = 0
links = []
for j in search(Cities[x],start=0, stop=3, pause=2): 
    links = links[:] + [j]
    y.append(links)
    x = x + 1
print(links)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here with `links`? You reset it to an empty list on each iteration, so it is always empty, and then you do `links = links[:] + [j]` but `links[:]` then I'd pointless, and you could just do `links = [j]`... But I don't think that's what you intended? It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of Python ;). I started my journey one year ago (with 20 years of .net experience)

I see that you are only looping (for) in your search result, but you are not looping through your cities.  So that's why I created two nested loops.  One for your cities and one for every result you get back.  I also changed to a list, but you could obviously keep using an array if you prefer that

This should work, I believe:

```py
links = list()
for city in Cities :
    for result in search(city, start=0, stop=3, pause=2): 
        links.append(result)
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Really help me out and all the support I get from here keep me motivated! :)